# Javascript get element by select class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <select class="tmcp-field tillagg-width tm-epo-field tmcp-select"
                name="tmcp_select_30"
                data-price=""
                data-rules="" 
                data-original-rules=""                 
                id="tmcp_select_75"
                tabindex="75">
            <option  value="5 (480 mm)_0" etc.......
```

To get value of this element, currently I am using this piece of code:

```
document.getElementById("tmcp_select_75").value
```

It works well, but how can I get value of element using `"tmcp-field tillagg-width tm-epo-field tmcp-select"` seen it top row of first code sample? Thanks :)

Comment: try `document.getElementsByClassName("tmcp-field tillagg-width tm-epo-field tmcp-select")`

Comment: You tagged jQuery, so `$(".tmcp-field.tillagg-width.tm-epo-field.tmcp-select")` should work.

Comment: `$(".tmcp-field.tillagg-width.tm-epo-field.tmcp-select").val()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Use* [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) or [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

```
// Gets the first match's
document.querySelector(".tmcp-field.tillagg-width.tm-epo-field.tmcp-select")

// Gets a collection of the selects;
document.querySelectorAll(".tmcp-field.tillagg-width.tm-epo-field.tmcp-select")

// Gets a collection of the selects;
document.getElementsByClassName("tmcp-field tillagg-width tm-epo-field tmcp-select")
```

*jQuery*

```
$(".tmcp-field.tillagg-width.tm-epo-field.tmcp-select")
```

Comment: Hey Satpal, is `querySelector` better than `getElementsByClassName` ?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, I prefer as it give flexibility, you don't need to use various methods

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen: "Better" is subjective, but `getElementsByClassName` isn't as well supported and can only do class names rather than full selectors.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is also much, *much* faster: https://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-queryselectorall/18. The caveat here is that it's not as well supported in legacy browsers, such as IE8

Comment: But @Satpal I think `className` is better. because it is reserved only for classes.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: By "it" you mean `getElementsByClassName`, I'm assuming. It's certainly faster in the single-class case; is that true for multiple classes as well?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I edited the comment to make it clearer. I haven't done the testing personally, but I'd imagine it's quicker for cases with multiple classes too.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: [Seems to be](https://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-qsall-multi-classes), at least in terms of the call itself. I wonder if add/remove performance is impacted, e.g., if the browser has to add to the list of live collections to keep updated if you throw a lot of multi-class GEBCN calls at it. Micro-opt, of course, either way until/unless there's a problem. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need jQuery for this. If I'm reading you right, you want to select the element using its class instead of by ID, as you're doing right now. Use document.querySelector:

`document.querySelector('.tmcp-field.tillagg-width.tm-epo-field.tmcp-select');`

You probably don't need to select for all of those classes, so remove any that you don't need to narrow down the result.

Comment: E.g., what Satpal said. (And me, but then I saw his and deleted mine.)